# Windows CE uses UTF-16 or UCS-2?

Tags: unicode, windows-ce, character-encoding

Windows NT only supported UCS-2, then starting with Windows 2000 it started to support UTF-16.

But what about Windows CE? It still supports only UCS-2 or the native charset is now UTF-16?

Comment: "Support" in what context?  In API calls?  In character display?  Something else?

Comment: @ctacke: in all the applicable contexts.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN:

[Working With Unicode Surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms904394.aspx)

> Windows CE [5.0] provides Unicode surrogate
>   support at the OS level and in
>   Microsoft® Internet Explorer. The
>   support is limited to surrogate
>   handling and display; editing is not
>   supported.